# What's this meaning of `xxx@xxx` in a GitHub open source project?

Tags: github

When reading an open source project, I sometimes come across icons like these below; when I click this example, it will go to the AFNetworking open source project.

[image]

What's this for? Is it just a link not a directory which contains code?

Comment: It appears to be a [git submodule](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GitSubmodules/article.html) link. The part before the @ names the project and the part after the @ the revision that is being linked to.

Answer (score 6):

This means it is a git submodule, you can find more information in [git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

in this project, when you download it, you should add the `--recursive` param:

```
git clone --recursive [URL to Git repo]
```

then you can download the `git submodule` of this GitHub project.